# list folders and sub folders in java

Tags: java, directory

I have been trying to display a folder list in Java using this code :

```
class Folder {
   boolean isFile;
   String folderName;
   List<Folder> subFolders = new ArrayList<Folder>;
}

class ListF {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      File fname = new File("C:/hello");
      Folder obj = new Folder();
      if (fname.isDirectory()) {
         File[] fileNames;
         fileNames = fname.listFiles();
         for (i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
            obj.subFolders.add(fileNames[i]);
         }
         System.out.println("The list is " + obj.subFolders);
      }
   }
}
```

But I am getting an error in my code:

```
ListF.java:5: '(' or '[' expected List<Folder> subFolders=new ArrayList<Folder>;
```

Can anyone point out my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `new ArrayList<Folder>;` by `new ArrayList<Folder>();`

Answer (score 1):

`List<Folder> subFolders = new ArrayList<Folder>;`

**Make the above statement as :**

```
List<Folder> subFolders = new ArrayList<Folder>();
```

**Or**

If you are using Java 7 and above, you can do this too....

```
List<Folder> subFolders = new ArrayList<>();
```